# Django - Models: for loop in query/filter

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a list of reviews and each review has a rating average. My problem is trying to added each review id to the filter for the query result. For this, I assume a for loop in the filter is best.

I've found a previous post with a similar situation, but the same result doesn't seem to be working for me.

When I load my reviews page, I receive a TypeError: `'function' object is not iterable`.

Here is my view.py file with the queries.

```
def reviews(request):
    context = {
        'reviews': Employee.objects.all(),

        'rating': Employee.objects.filter(id__in=[review.id for review in reviews]).aggregate(rate=Avg(F('value1')+F('value2')+F('value3').....+F('valueN'))/N)
    }
    return render(request, 'reviews/reviews.html', context)
```

`Reviews.html` template.

```
{% extends "reviews/layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for review in reviews %}
      {% for rating in ratings %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ review.author.profile.image.url }}">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <h4 class="mr-2">{{ review.company }} {{rating}}</h4>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ review.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
            </div>
            <h5><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'review-detail' review.id %}">{{ review.title }}</a></h5>
            <p class="article-content">{{ review.content }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

EDIT: Here is my model for the Employee table.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    recommend = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    salary = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    salary_satis = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    culture = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    work_env = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    communication = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    opportunity = models.CharField(max_length=100) # Opportunity happiness
    leadership_satis = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fair_treatment = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    advice = models.TextField() # Advice for management
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_posted']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title, self.content, self.company, self.recommend, self.salary, self.salary_satis, self.culture, self.location, self.work_env, self.communication, self.opportunity, self.leadership_satis, self.fair_treatment, self.advice, self.date_posted, self.author}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # Returns user to reviews page after their review has been submitted.
        return reverse('reviews')
```

Comment: Your `reviews` refers to the view function, not to the value associated with the `'reviews'` key, since that is just a key, not an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Your `reviews` in the dictionary, refers to the `reviews` view function (here both in boldface):

```
def reviews(request):
    context = {
        'reviews': Employee.objects.all(),
        'rating': Employee.objects.filter(
            id__in=[review.id for review in reviews]
        ).aggregate(
            rate=Avg(F('value1')+F('value2')+F('value3').....+F('valueN'))/N
        )
    }
    return render(request, 'reviews/reviews.html', context)
```

Indeed, you can not iterate over this function, since it has no `__iter__` method attached to it, but even if it had, this is not what you want to do.

I think the most elegant way to solve this, is simply defining a `reviews` variable:

```
def reviews(request):
    reviews = Employee.objects.all()
    context = {
        'reviews': reviews,
        'rating': Employee.objects.filter(
            id__in=[review.id for review in reviews]
        ).aggregate(
            rate=Avg(F('value1')+F('value2')+F('value3').....+F('valueN'))/N
        )
    }
    return render(request, 'reviews/reviews.html', context)
```

So now `reviews` is a local variable that you can acces, and since a queryseet is iterable, we can iterate over this.

That being said, it is a bit odd to use an `id__in` here, since `reviews` has *all* the `Employee`s.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I you made a good point about the variable. I took your advice above. The avg rating is there, but it looks like it's the avg rating for everyone combined. Every review has the same exact rating. I'm trying to figure out what went wrong. Also, I tried to load the page without the `id__in` and it had an error, `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'`

Comment: Well here with `aggregate` you make a dictionary with *one* element: the average of the average of the values. If you want to *annotate* (so one `rate` per `Employee`, you should `.annotate(..)`, and thus `.annotate(rate=(F('value')+ ...)/N)` *without* the `Avg`.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. I replaced aggregate with annotate and removed the avg. When I refreshed the page, it was like an explosion of data. Where the rating goes there was all the data for each review. This was the same for every review. Not just numbers, but all the data from the db table. I appreciate your help thus far. I'll keep looking at it.

Comment: @asdf123: are these values from a *related* model?

Comment: They are all from the same table. To make sure I've understood correctly, I have added my Employee model in the question, above.